# Daily limit has been exceeded cpanel

Tags: python, email, smtp, cpanel

I have a mail account on cpanel. I use it to send spam mailings to my users. At the moment, their number is 1800. But I ran into a problem, after one mailing, an error is returned to me:

```
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'blabla@gmail.com': (550, b '"Daily limit has been exceeded for blabla@bla.io "')}
```

I tried to search for submission limits but could not find information on the either my hosting or cpanel. Is it possible to remove this limitation and what is its number.
I use the script to send messages:

```
class EmailThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, subject, html_content, recipient_list, sender):
        self.subject = subject
        self.recipient_list = recipient_list
        self.html_content = html_content
        self.sender = sender
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        msg = EmailMessage(self.subject, self.html_content, self.sender, bcc=self.recipient_list)
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.send()

def send_html_mail(subject, html_content, recipient_list, sender):
    EmailThread(subject, html_content, recipient_list, sender).start()

send_html_mail(subject=form.cleaned_data['theme'], html_content=msg_html,
                               sender=f'blabla.io <{getattr(settings, "EMAIL_HOST_USER")}>', recipient_list=[form.cleaned_data['to']])
```

Answer (score 0):

it means you've hit your email sending limit per hour and per day
try to use a local smtp for spam or other services with mass email